# Pass data from one view to another view in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I am a learner in MVC, I am facing a issue in passing data, I want to pass a data from one view to another view in MVC, How can I do this? help me, 
I will select the firstname in one view and I want to pass the firstname to another view?

Comment: Are you asking about the concept of MVC, or a specific MVC framework implementation?

Comment: I need the concept for passing the data from one view to other view.

Answer (score 0):

Views don't communicate with other views.

Consider this illustration from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

[image]

A view doesn't connect to another view.  It is simply an interface presented to the user.  Data which originates in a view (such as user input) would then be passed to a controller, which in turn directs (controls) the data/logic flow of the application.  (Not the logic itself, the flow of the logic.)

That controller will then interact with the models (if necessary, sometimes the only action for a controller to perform is to immediately render another view, such as a redirect in a web application) and present the next view.

If data sent to the controller is needed in the next view, it would be the responsibility of the controller to include it in the next view.

Comment: okay, I will get the data from view, how can I pass the data to the controller?

Comment: @durai: That's an implementation detail of the technology being used.  It's unrelated to the MVC pattern itself.  Whatever mechanism is used to transmit data is fine, as long as data is passed from the view to the controller.

Comment: can you share a Example code for passing value from view to controller

Comment: @durai: Well, in a web application it would likely be a form post to the server.  So something like: `<form method="POST" action="/some/action"><input type="text" name="myInput" /><input type="submit"></form>`  It's not really clear what you're looking for, though.  In your question you *explicitly* stated (twice) that you are *not* talking about a specific framework or technology, but just asking about the MVC pattern in general.  Patterns don't have code.